# How to eval spark.ml model without DataFrames/SparkContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

With Spark MLLib, I'd build a model (like `RandomForest`), and then it was possible to eval it outside of Spark by loading the model and using `predict` on it passing a vector of features.

It seems like with Spark ML, `predict` is now called `transform` and only acts on a `DataFrame`.

Is there any way to build a `DataFrame` outside of Spark since it seems like one needs a SparkContext to build a DataFrame?

Am I missing something?

Comment: it still has `predict`, `predictProbablity` and `predictRaw` methods working on vectors, can't you use them?

Comment: I don't see those methods in the docs:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel   
Where do you see these for RandomForest in spark.ml?

Comment: well theoretically you probably could write a class extending the RFClassictionaModel (using scala packages) from ml and make some public methods exposing the above protected ones but not sure if it's the best way. Can't you use the implementation from `mllib` package? I'm not sure if they are still supporting it but it's there

Comment: my understanding is that spark ml supersedes mllib and mllib is due to be deprecated at some point. I used mllib before, but I am trying to get the probabilities for each class, and this feature is only available since recently, and only on the spark ml implementation

Comment: Yes you are correct unfortunately... Have you had a look at H2O? Not sure if they have the probabilities you are looking for (;-)) but there you can expprt your models as pojo and use them anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Re: *Is there any way to build a DataFrame outside of Spark?*

It is not possible. DataFrames live inside SQLContext with it living in SparkContext. Perhaps you could work it around *somehow*, but the whole story is that the connection between DataFrames and SparkContext is by design.

Comment: well, this is not the answer I want to hear... Spark seems to be going backward if this is the case. It's a powerful tool to train models, but be forced to use it to eval is plain annoying. Is there a way to export the model in a format that can be used without DataFrames

Comment: Think so. You can export a model, but I know very little to say how useful it could be. What information about a model would you like to save (persist)?

Comment: I know i can save a model, this is what I have been doing with MLLib. what I want is a format I can load as an object I can then run eval on. In mllib I could save a RandomForestModel as such and then load it somewhere else, and run eval passing it a vector. in ML there seem to be no way to do this. I need to be able to eval outside of Spark.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with MLlib then? Every benefit you get from using ML is tightly bound to `DataFrame` as a data structure. If you strip all `DataFrame` related features (schema transformation, metadata processing) you get a plain MLlib model or something equivalent anyway.

Comment: @MrE, did you ever figure this out? I'm working on a project where we're trying to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to use spark models outside of spark context (using PMML):

1. You create model with a pipeline like this:

`SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();`

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();   
String tableName = "schema.table";
Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
dbProperties.setProperty("user",vKey);
dbProperties.setProperty("password",password);
dbProperties.setProperty("AuthMech","3");
dbProperties.setProperty("source","jdbc");
dbProperties.setProperty("driver","com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver");
String tableName = "schema.table";
String simpleUrl = "jdbc:impala://host:21050/schema"
Dataset<Row> data = session.read().jdbc(simpleUrl ,tableName,dbProperties);
String[] inputCols = {"column1"};
StringIndexer indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("column1").setOutputCol("indexed_column1");
StringIndexerModel alphabet  = indexer.fit(data);
data = alphabet.transform(data);
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(inputCols).setOutputCol("features");
Predictor p = new GBTRegressor();
p.set("maxIter",20);
p.set("maxDepth",2);
p.set("maxBins",204);
p.setLabelCol("faktor");
PipelineStage[] stages = {indexer,assembler, p};
Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline();
pipeline.setStages(stages);
PipelineModel pmodel = pipeline.fit(data);
PMML pmml = ConverterUtil.toPMML(data.schema(),pmodel);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("model.pmml");
JAXBUtil.marshalPMML(pmml,new StreamResult(fos));
```

2. Using PPML for predictions (locally, without spark context, which can be applied to a Map of arguments and not on a DataFrame):

   ```
   PMML pmml = org.jpmml.model.PMMLUtil.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(pmmlFile));
   ModelEvaluatorFactory modelEvaluatorFactory = ModelEvaluatorFactory.newInstance();
   MiningModelEvaluator evaluator = (MiningModelEvaluator) modelEvaluatorFactory.newModelEvaluator(pmml);
   inputFieldMap = new HashMap<String, Field>();     
   Map<FieldName,String> args = new HashMap<FieldName, String>();
   Field curField = evaluator.getInputFields().get(0);
   args.put(curField.getName(), "1.0");
   Map<FieldName, ?> result  = evaluator.evaluate(args);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Spent days on this problem too. It's not straightforward. My third suggestion involves code I have written specifically for this purpose.

**Option 1**

As other commenters have said, [predict(Vector)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel) is now available. However, you need to know how to construct a vector. If you don't, see Option 3.

**Option 2**

If the goal is to avoid setting up a Spark server (standalone or cluster modes), then its possible to start Spark in local mode. The whole thing will run inside a single JVM.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()
// create dataframe from file, or make it up from some data in memory
// use model.transform() to get predictions
```

But this brings unnecessary dependencies to your prediction module, and it consumes resources in your JVM at runtime. Also, if prediction latency is critical, for example making a prediction within a millisecond as soon as a request comes in, then this option is too slow.

**Option 3**

MLlib [FeatureHasher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/FeatureHasher.html)'s output can be used as an input to your learner. The class is good for one hot encoding and also for fixing the size of your feature dimension. You can use it even when all your features are numerical. If you use that in your training, then all you need at prediction time is the hashing logic there. Its [implemented](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/FeatureHasher.scala#L168) as a spark transformer so it's not easy to re-use outside of a spark environment. So I have done the work of pulling out the hashing function to a lib. You apply FeatureHasher and your learner during training as normal. Then here's how you use the slimmed down hasher at prediction time:

```
// Schema and hash size must stay consistent across training and prediction
val hasher = new FeatureHasherLite(mySchema, myHashSize)

// create sample data-point and hash it
val feature = Map("feature1" -> "value1", "feature2" -> 2.0, "feature3" -> 3, "feature4" -> false)
val featureVector = hasher.hash(feature)

// Make prediction
val prediction = model.predict(featureVector)
```

You can see details in my github at [tilayealemu/sparkmllite](https://github.com/tilayealemu/sparkmllite). If you'd rather copy my code, take a look at [FeatureHasherLite.scala](https://github.com/tilayealemu/sparkmllite/blob/master/sparkml-lite/src/main/scala/com/ainsightful/sparkml/lite/FeatureHasherLite.scala).There are sample codes and unit tests too. Feel free to create an issue if you need help.